# C# - Reflection - Get propriety of array in all index

Tags: c#, arrays, system.reflection

I have two classes:

```
public class Car
{
    public string color { get; set; }
    public string model { get; set; }
}

public class myclass
{
    public Car[] car { get; set; }
}
```

and one instance :

```
myclass c = new myclass()
{
    car = new Car[]
    {
        new Car()
        {
            color = "blue",
            model = "my model"
        },
        new Car()
        {
            color = "green",
            model = "my model 2"
        }
    }
};

var car = c.GetType().GetProperty("car").GetValue(c, null);
```

var car = :

[image: var car]

How can I loop over all indexes of the array `car` and get the property `color` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more generic way, will try converting it into [IEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) so your collection will not be bind to array alone.

```
var cars = c.GetType().GetProperty("car").GetValue(c) as IEnumerable<object>;
foreach (var car in cars)
{
    Console.WriteLine(car.GetType().GetProperty("color").GetValue(car));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use reflection to do the looping, you could try something like this:

```
//gets the value of myclass's car property--an array of type Car[] returned as an object
var cars = c.GetType().GetProperty("car").GetValue(c, null);

if (cars.GetType().IsArray)//should be true for you
{
    //gets the type of the elements of the array: Car
    var carArrayElementType = cars.GetType().GetElementType();

    //gets the color property of Car
    var colorProp = carArrayElementType.GetProperty("color");

    //lets you loop through the cars array
    var carEnumerable = cars as IEnumerable;

    foreach (var car in carEnumerable)
    {
        //returns the color property's value as a string
        var color = colorProp.GetValue(car, null) as string;

       //use color
    }
}
```

That said, the more straight forward way to loop over all indexes of the array `car` and get the property `color` without having to use reflection would be something like:

```
foreach(var car in c.car)
{
    var color = car.color;

    //use color
}
```

Comment: thank's but i don't know the type Car. How to use the dynamic type for Car ?

Comment: Oh! I updated my answer--is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you are asking, by the looks of it this has nothing to do with reflection... If you simply want to iterate all cars in `c.car` you can use a foreach or for loop.

```
foreach (Car car in c.car)
{ Console.Writeline(car.color); }

for (int i = 0; i < c.car.length; ++i)
{ Console.Writeline(c.car[i].color); }
```

By the looks of it however you havent understood the basics of programming and c# properties. I suggest you find a codestyle and stick to it, generally i would recommend UpperCamelCase for properties and classes. You ought to take a look at [microsofts documentation on properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to just cast the returned object from GetValue to a Car[] array and then just loop around it.

```
var cars = c.GetType().GetProperty("car").GetValue(c, null) as Car[];

foreach (Car c in cars)
{
   Debug.WriteLine("the color is " + c.color.ToString());
}
```